# Q: Python stops working at end of script in Batch

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-file

I'm running a series of python scripts from the Command window via a batch file.

Previously, it's worked without issue. However now, without a change in code, every time it gets to the end of a script I get a "Python.exe has stopped working" error. The scripts have actually completed processing, but I need to close the error window for the batch to proceed.

I've tried adding sys.exit to ends of the scripts but that makes no difference. The first script has no issue but every script after has this issue.

How do I stop this error from happening?

**Batch File**

```
C:\Path\to\Python\ArcGIS64bitversion C:\Path\to\Script1
C:\Path\to\Python\ArcGIS64bitversion C:\Path\to\Script2
C:\Path\to\Python\ArcGIS64bitversion C:\Path\to\Script3
C:\Path\to\Python\ArcGIS64bitversion C:\Path\to\Script4a
C:\Path\to\Python\ArcGIS64bitversion C:\Path\to\Script4b
C:\Path\to\Python\ArcGIS64bitversion C:\Path\to\Script4c
C:\Path\to\Python\ArcGIS64bitversion C:\Path\to\Script4d
C:\Path\to\Python\ArcGIS64bitversion C:\Path\to\Script5
C:\Path\to\Python\ArcGIS64bitversion C:\Path\to\Script6
```

the python scripts do, all, actually complete. Scripts 2-5 all use multiprocessing, however script 6 does not use multiprocessing and still experiences the error.

**General Script Structure**

```
import statements
global variables
get data statements

Def Code:
    try: 
        code
        sys.exit
    except:
        print error in text file

Def multiprocessing:
    pool = multiprocessing.pool(32)
    pool.map(Code, listofData)

if main statement
    try:
        code
        multiprocessing()
        sys.exit
    except:
        print error to text file
```

**Script 2 (the first script to error)**

```
import arcpy, fnmatch, os, shutil, sys, traceback
import multiprocessing
from time import strftime
#===========================================================================================
ras_dir = r'C:\Path\to\Input'
working_dir = r'C:\Path\to\Output'
output_dir = os.path.join(working_dir, 'Results')
if not os.path.isdir(output_dir):
    os.mkdir(output_dir)
#===========================================================================================        
global input_files1
global raslist
global ras
raslist = []
input_files1 = []
#===========================================================================================        
for r, d, f in os.walk(working_dir):
    for inFile in fnmatch.filter(f, '*.shp'):
        input_files1.append(os.path.join(r, inFile))

for r, d, f in os.walk(ras_dir):
    for rasf in fnmatch.filter(f,'*.tif'):
        raslist.append(os.path.join(r, rasf))

ras = raslist[0]        
del rasf,raslist    

def rasextract(file):

    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    proj = file.split('.')
    proj = proj[0] + '.' + proj[1] + '.prj'
    arcpy.env.outputCoordinateSystem = arcpy.SpatialReference(proj)

    try:

        filename = str(file)
        filename = filename.split('\\')
        filename = filename[-1]
        filename = filename.split('.')
        filename = filename[0]

        tif_dir = output_dir + '\\' + filename
        os.mkdir(tif_dir)
        arcpy.env.workspace = tif_dir
        arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = tif_dir

        dname = tif_dir + '\\' + filename + '_ras.tif'
        fname = working_dir+ '\\' + filename + '_ras.tif'
        bufname = tif_dir + '\\' + filename + '_rasbuf.shp'

        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(file, bufname, "550 METERS", "FULL", "ROUND", "ALL")

        newras = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(ras, bufname)
        newras.save(rasname)

        print "Saved " + filename + " ras"
        sys.exit


    except:
        var = traceback.format_exc()
        x = str(var)
        timecode = strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S + 0000")
        logfile = open(r'C:\ErrorLogs\Log_Script2_rasEx.txt', "a+")
    ent = "\n"
        logfile.write(timecode + "             " + x + ent)
        logfile.close()

def MCprocess():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(32)
    pool.map(rasextract, input_files1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:

        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")  
        ras_dir = r'C:\Path\to\Input'
        working_dir = r'C:\Path\to\Output'
        output_dir = os.path.join(working_dir, 'Results')
        if not os.path.isdir(output_dir):
            os.mkdir(output_dir)
        #=============================================================      
        raslist = []
        input_files1 = []
        #=============================================================      
        for r, d, f in os.walk(working_dir):
            for inFile in fnmatch.filter(f, '*.shp'):
                input_files1.append(os.path.join(r, inFile))

        for r, d, f in os.walk(ras_dir):
            for demf in fnmatch.filter(f,'*.tif'):
                demlist.append(os.path.join(r, rasf))

        ras = raslist[0]        
        del rasf,raslist
        MCprocess()
        sys.exit

    except:
        var = traceback.format_exc()
        x = str(var)
        timecode = strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S + 0000")
        logfile = open(r'C:\ErrorLogs\Log_Script2_rasEx.txt', "a+")
        ent = "\n"
        logfile.write(timecode + "             " + x + ent)
        logfile.close()
```

**NEW error message**

this error was encountered after disabling error reporting.

[image]

Comment: sorry my crystal ball is out for repair...

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some debugging. You could add in more `sys.exits()` and see exactly which part of your code is causing the python.exe to stop working or use a python debugger

Comment: A little more information might help everybody better understand what's going on. My first thought is that it sounds like python is crashing or hanging up due to some processing it is attempting to do. (Hard to know without seeing actual code). Are all of your scripts actually running to completion? That's where I'd start if I were you....confirm that each and every script is running to completion.

Also, are all of the scripts doing near-identical types of operations?

Comment: If you wish your question not to be closed as off-topic, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48214382/edit), adding the content of your batch file and any problematic python script(s).

Comment: Added a bunch more information.

Comment: Is it possible this is related to the Meltdown update? If I recall correctly it only started happening after Windows pushed that update on Wednesday.

Answer (score 0):

Windows is catching the error.

Try disabling 'Window Error Reporting' in the Registry. After that a traceback/error should be shown. [Here](https://superuser.com/q/950997) you find instructions how to disable 'WER' for Windows 10.

Comment: My machine is windows 7, currently testing this answer.

Comment: Doesn't work. Now I get a direct python.exe error stating the same thing. The script has still completely run and run correctly.

Comment: What do you mean ? Instead of a windows error dialog, the error message is printed to stdout ?

Comment: I'll post a picture in the question post of the new error

Comment: ... you didnt disable WER. The dialog show is trigger through windows WerFault.exe.

Comment: I did though. In windows 7 you go into the control panel and then action center and change problem reporting settings and change to never check for solutions. This is what I've done. The error box changed from windows to python. I'm not sure what to tell you, but I've definitely disabled it the way I'm supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

*Posting this as it is the only web search I could find matching my error (which was that a script ran flawlessly in IDLE, but threw the "Python has stopped working" error when called from a batch (.bat) file) - Full disclosure, I was using shelve, not using arcpy.*

I think the issue is that you are somehow leaving files 'open', and then when the script ends Python is forced to clean up the open files in an 'unplanned' fashion.  Inside the IDE, this is caught and handled, but once in a batch file, the issue bubbles up to give the 'stopped working'

contrast:

```
f = open("example.txt", "r")
```

with

```
f = open("example.txt", "r")
f.close()
```

The first will error out from a bat file, the second will not.